# Is there a way to register new CoffeeScript extensions for require?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, require, file-extension

I'm currently calling my test files something like `test.coffee.unit` for unit tests... (which produces the output `test.spec.unit`)

However, when calling `require "test.coffee.unit"` node interprets the file as javascript and it fails to evaluate. I've been looking through the docs and https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js#L192 to see if I could find a way, but I'm not seeing anything that looks promising.

I also had a look at https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L347 and http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together to see what I could glean from that...

**Summary:**

Is there a way to register the `.coffee.unit` or just `.unit` extension so that `require` will evaluate it as CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Modify the `coffee-script` source.
2. Extract the parts of the source you need, and modify them to work in a different scope.

For either, you'll want to refer to [*section-19* of the `coffee-script` `node` module](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/coffee-script.html#section-19).

The relevant code shows how to configure a require extension:

```
if require.extensions
  for ext in ['.coffee', '.litcoffee', '.coffee.md']
    require.extensions[ext] = loadFile
```

And the code `coffee-script` uses to load a file:

```
loadFile = (module, filename) ->
  raw = fs.readFileSync filename, 'utf8'
  stripped = if raw.charCodeAt(0) is 0xFEFF then raw.substring 1 else raw
  answer = compile(stripped, {filename, sourceMap: true, literate: helpers.isLiterate filename})
  sourceMaps[filename] = answer.sourceMap
  module._compile answer.js, filename
```

You'll need to track down the dependencies.  Most are on the `coffee-script` module's exports.  For example,

```
compile(stripped, {filename, sourceMap: true, literate: helpers.isLiterate filename})
```

To

```
cs = require 'coffee-script'
cs.compile(stripped, {filename, sourceMap: true, literate: cs.helpers.isLiterate filename})
```

Feel more than welcome to edit this answer with a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks!! It's unfortunate that coffee doesn't have a simpler mechanism to register extensions. Good answer...

Comment: Yeah... it's a simple solution to change the code.  It just needs to export `loadFile`.